# How to search through folders for a certain file using Powershell

Tags: windows, powershell, sccm

I am writing an uninstall script for Office using Powershell. I need the script to search through:

```
    C:\windows\ccmcache\
```

There are a number of folders in there. Is there a way to find which folder has the contents that I am looking for? So let's say I am looking for a folder that contains:

1. office.en-us
2. office64.en-us

and so on. How can I return that exact path? Because that is where I am running the uninstall from but the catch is I don't know what folder Office is in the ccmcahce folder.

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: Seeing as this is already marked answered I just want to comment, that the answers are all correct from a ps view, but from an sccm point of view I have to remark that there is no guarantee that any file is within your cache. once it's full everything could be overwritten so to be sure you have to use the setup.exe like in the original setup. path relativ to the position of the distributed content and sccm will then download it for you and *know* the folder within ccmcache.... alternative would be to look in registry uninstall for the id to uninstall and use the msi cache instead of sccm cache

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Tomalak when running the code you posted it works if there aren't a large number of files and folders to sort through, but if you really have no idea where the file or folder you're looking for lives at then specifying a -recurse parameter would be helpful

```
Get-Childitem "C:\*\Office.en-us" -Recurse
```

While this is sometimes necessary (in this case it doesn't seem to be), it can take an extended amount of time to run if there are large folders to sort through...

Answer (score 3):

No loop needed.

```
dir "C:\windows\ccmcache\*\Office.en-us" -Directory
```

Note that `dir` is an alias for [`Get-ChildItem`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem).

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. Exactly what I was looking for. One more question, does this look right? I am very new to Powershell.         
                                                                                                                
        $path = dir "C:\windows\ccmcahce\*\Office.en-us" -Directory                        
        Start-Process $path\setup.exe /uninstall ProPlus /config Uninstall.xml -Wait

Comment: That code in your comment looks correct @Ben, as long as the parameters you're using are correct and it is two lines of code. Line 1: $Path = dir etc.. Line 2: Start-Process etc..

Comment: @CoryEtmund Yea it is two lines. Thanks you.

Comment: @CoryEtmund When I run echo $path\setup.exe it is showing:  C:\windows\ccmcache\c\office.en-us\setup.exe   but I want it to show: C:\windows\ccmcache\c\setup.exe   Do you know how to fix this?

Comment: then your $Path variable should be $Path = "C:\windows\ccmcache\\*\setup.exe" instead of looking for Office.en-us, unless i'm misunderstanding

Comment: @CoryEtmund It can't be setup.exe because there are other folders that contain setup.exe. This particular folder is different from every other one because of the Office.en-us folder. I just needed the script to ID what path it was in so I can run the setup.exe

Comment: If that path will be the same everytime this script is ran, you could leave out the get-childitem part and just set $Path = 'C:\windows\ccmcache\c" and then do Start-Process $Path\setup.exe /uninstall ProPlus /config Uninstall.xml -Wait

Comment: @CoryEtmund But what I am trying to figure out is what folder is in the ccmcache. So I didn't know it was c until I ran the original code. It could be a,b,c,d,e,f etc..

Comment: Line 1: $Path = Get-Childitem "C:\windows\ccmcache\\*\Office.en-us" -Recurse     Line 2: $SetupPath = Split-Path -Parent "$Path"    Line 3: Start-Process $SetupPath\setup.exe parameters      please give that a try. The split-path should return the parent folder of the office.en-us which according to what you've said so far also contains the setup.exe

Comment: @CoryEtmund I see. I gave it a shot and it didn't work. It is giving me the contents of the Office.en-us folder. What I want is the path to the c folder. C:\windows\ccmcache\**C** So is there anyway to go back in the path? Something like C:\windows\ccmcache\C\office\cd..

Comment: Guys, do you think you can start a chat room or discuss this not in the comments to my answer? :)

Comment: sorry about that Tomalak! @Ben , with a little more research i'm sure you'll figure out your exact solution very soon as I feel like I have gotten you much closer to it. Good luck!